# When is open mortgage better than closed mortgage?

Tags: canada, mortgage

The interest rates on open mortgages (where I can pay more than the minimal payment towards the principal) are higher than closed mortgages (where prepaying has penalty).

How can I tell which one is more economic in the long run? Is there an online tool that lets you compare different scenarios?

Comment: Even though this is a general question, do you mind mentioning country? I am in the US and not heard of this option. Usually a bank either has pre-payment penalty or it doesn't , here.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yeah, I see no contradiction. see [here](http://www.scotiabank.com/ca/en/0,,1112,00.html) for example.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a spreadsheet exercise.

Set up to calculate the "loss" (from not being allowed any pre-pay) over the term of loan. Then calculate the cost of the higher rate.

You can calculate the extreme case, and know that your gain/loss is in a certain range. In the end, if rates shoot up, prepaying is bad for you. Why prepay a 4% loan if CD rates are 5%?